# All Mp3 Files downloaded with 3kb only and corrupt

Tags: php

This code force downloads fine for me on both Chrome and Mozilla. But the issue is that all file size are 3kb. Why? The sizes are different like 3MB, 4MB, 3.5MB and the download file is just a corrupt 3kb... Kindly help please.

**Note:** If a use a header redirection, it downloads fine in Chrome or opens in other browsers and start playing without downloading.

```
<?php
    //Bring in My functions
    require_once ('../inc/functions.php');
    //Bring in my header
    require_once ('../inc/header.php');
?>
<!-- Page body starts -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9 contentArea">      
<?php
//Get File, Check For Existence and Download
//Get File, Check For Existence and Download
        if(isset($_GET['file'])){
            $file = sanitizeMySQL($con, $_GET['file']);
            $checkFile = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE f_song = '$file' AND f_del='0'";
            $checkFileRun = mysqli_query($con, $checkFile);
            $fileName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkFileRun);
            //$song = $fileName['f_song'];
            if($fileName['f_song']==null || $fileName['f_song'] == ""){
                echo '<h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-3x red"></i><br />Sorry! This is does not Exist on this Server or has been moved</h4>';
            }else{
                $updateDownload = "UPDATE b_files SET f_count={$fileName['f_count']}+1 WHERE f_song ='$file' AND f_del='0'";
                $updateDownloadRun = mysqli_query($con, $updateDownload);
                $filePath = SITE_URL."music/".$file;
                $fileSize = filesize($filePath);
                header("Cache-Control: public");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
                header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                //Read the file
                readfile($filePath);        
                //header("Location:".SITE_URL.'music/'.urldecode($fileName['file_song_name']));
                exit();
            }
        }elseif(!isset($_GET['file'])){
            echo '<h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-3x red"></i><br />Sorry! File Not Found</h4>';
        }
//File Download Ends
        ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Call In The SideBar -->
        <?php require_once '../inc/sidebar.php'; ?>
    </div>

<?php
    require_once ('../inc/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: use the full local path `/path/to/mp3` instead of  `SITE_URL` in `$filePath = SITE_URL."music/".$file`

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I have tried it to be 101% sure. `SITE_URL."music/".$file` and `/path/to/my/mp3` is still the same output

Comment: Open the mp3 file in your code editor. The error message should be in your 3kb mp3 file.

Comment: I opened the mp3 file in a notepad and all that's in there is the file path
`http://localhost/du/my-mp3 file.mp3`
which i copy to my url again and it downloaded the correct file for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the readfile, you have already written included files and some HTML to the output buffer. This will result in a corrupted media file. You may want to put the readfile and exit (or die()) before outing any HTML content.

And SITE_URL wouldn't work for $filePath. You may need to find the correct file path by prepending

```
...dirname(dirname(__file__))...
```

Comment: Thanks **Vishva8kumara**. I have remove all output and it download with Zero byte in size. Below is the new code

Comment: Block comment the header parts for now, so that you would rather see the mp3 file content on browser. This would be easier for debugging the code, so layer you can un-comment the headers.

Comment: Then, in place of readfile, echo the $filePath and see if you got the correct file path.

Comment: If i echo the $filePath, nothing happens. Instead, it still download a corrupt file with 3kb

Comment: When you echo the $filePath, did you block comment the header(...) section.

Comment: Please open one of those 3kb files on notepad or your code editor and post it here. If that does not work, rename the extension to .txt and try. The answer should be there inside the raw content of your 3kb files.

Comment: I comment all header() and echo $filePath. Here is what echo to my browser
`http://localhost/du/music/hss del - Mama (Prod. kinda beats)-030517082912pm1493836152.mp3`

Comment: So this is the parameter you are going to pass into readfile. It is not going to work, because readfile expects the real path of the file, not web accessible path.

Try using dirname ( dirname ( __ file __ ) ) ..
echo dirname ( dirname ( __ file __ ) ) and see. You can encapsulate more dirname until you get the file path correct.

Comment: Hmm... i changed the filePath to
`$filePath = "C:\wamp\www\du\music\\".$file;`
and it downloaded the correct file but how about when i want to deloy this to the server? What do I do?

Comment: echo two underscores 'file' two underscores and this will give you the script path. You can use dirname function to get to the parent directory. So, without hard-coding the file path, get the absolute folder path to your project root folder. I hope you have mp3s relative to the script in same relative-ness on dev and live, so it should work fine then.

Comment: Thanks so much @vishva8kumara . You've really tried for me today. What do you want in return? Thanks so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143441/discussion-between-vishva8kumara-and-generah-ben).

Comment: Thanks so much @vishva8kumara . You've really tried for me today. What do you want in return? Thanks so much.
I also notice that after downloading the Mp3 file. It plays but the properties like title, artiste, genre got removed

Comment: I have a couple of open source projects: https://github.com/vishva8kumara/arc-reactor and https://github.com/villvay/veev I wish to popularize and get attention, but I have no idea how to spread them..

Comment: I think the artist and genre are stored in your media player, and not copied in the file itself.

Comment: In file properties, you can check the exact file size in bytes to see if any content of the file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Vishva8kumara**. I have remove all output and it download with Zero byte in size and the file is corrupt. Below is the new code

```
   <?php
    //Bring in My functions
    require_once ('../inc/functions.php');
//Get File, Check For Existence and Download
//Get File, Check For Existence and Download
        if(isset($_GET['file'])){
            $file = sanitizeMySQL($con, $_GET['file']);
            $checkFile = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE f_song = '$file' AND f_del='0'";
            $checkFileRun = mysqli_query($con, $checkFile);
            $fileName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkFileRun);
            //$song = $fileName['f_song'];
            if($fileName['f_song']==null || $fileName['f_song'] == ""){
                echo '<h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-3x red"></i><br />Sorry! This is does not Exist on this Server or has been moved</h4>';
            }else{
                $updateDownload = "UPDATE b_files SET f_count={$fileName['f_count']}+1 WHERE f_song ='$file' AND f_del='0'";
                $updateDownloadRun = mysqli_query($con, $updateDownload);
                $filePath = "http://localhost/du/music/".$file;
                $fileSize = filesize($filePath);
                header("Cache-Control: public");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
                header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                //Read the file
                readfile($filePath);        
                //header("Location:".SITE_URL.'music/'.urldecode($fileName['file_song_name']));
                exit();
            }
        }
?>
```